# Prove that the equation: ${a^k + b^k \equiv c^k}\mod{p}$ has no solutions under the following conditions

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Prove that the equation:  ${a^k + b^k \equiv c^k}\mod{p}$ has no solutions

where,
$ p $ is a prime $ > 3 $,
 $k = \frac{p - 1}{2} $,
and the condition $ 0 < a, b, c < p$ holds.

---

See my follow up question here [Check whether $k \in [0, p]$ in the equation: ${a^k + b^k \equiv c^k}\mod{p}$ has no solutions under the following conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861435/571724)

Comment: Hint: let $u = a^k, v = b^k, w = c^k$, we have $u^2 \equiv v^2 \equiv w^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Now $4u^2v^2 \equiv (w^2 - u^2 - v^2)^2 \pmod p \implies \cdots$

Comment: I like the start of achille hui's hint. It's pretty simple after the first step. What are the possibilities?

Comment: $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$ is the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @achillehui . Now it can be proved using Fermat's theorem as in tarit's answer.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to determine all values of `k` for which solutions doesn't exists. Shall I ask another question for this, or do I update this same question?

Comment: For the values of $k$ coprime with $p-1$, solutions always exist: in fact, what it happens is that any integer is a $k$-power. For k dividing $p-1$, it will depend on $p$ and $k$....

Comment: @xarles Yes, that is correct. But is there a way we can determine for which $k$ solution exists s.t. $k$ divides $p-1$? I have generated such $k$s for every prime < 100, and trying to find if there is some pattern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any natural number which satisfies $(a,p)=1$ with prime $p$, from Fermat's theorem we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. As, $0<a,b,c<p$, $(a,p)=(b,p)=(c,p)=1$. So all of $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}},b^{\frac{p-1}{2}},c^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ will satisfy the 
equation $x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Hence, $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$. Checking all $8$ cases the result easily follows.